# Sharepoint 2010: Scope in FullTextSqlQuery Results

Tags: 2010

I've been searching this for quite a while already and thinks that I should post here while still continuing my research.

Basically I'm using FullTextSqlQuery for searching but I can't pull out the scope property from the result items. I have scopes which are from different content sources (multiple intranet sites, not subsites).

Requirement:

Implement a filter/refiner based on my scopes. If there are 500 items from the search results, I should get the scope list these items came from.

I've tried including "ContentSource" managedproperty on my FullTextSqlQuery QueryText but it fails...

I'm not sure it this is even possible so I would need some enlightenment since I am not an expert. So, if there is a "proper" or more feasible way of doing this, please suggest. :)

Thanks in advance!